# Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd'

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I've put into finding a solution of my trouble about 3 hours, but havn't find the one!
Here is my security-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="ivan" authorities="ROLE_USER" password="ivan"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

my pom.xml snippet:

```
<properties>
    <spring-version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring-version>
    <spring-security-version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring-security-version>
    <hibernate-version>4.3.4.Final</hibernate-version>
</properties>
...
<!-- Spring security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Is it compatibility trouble between spring and spring-security versions? Or something else?

Comment: Do you have the `spring-security.jar` as a dependency in your pom?

Comment: @Jens, you can see the dependencies I use for spring-security

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! I have forund a solution! I should add th next dependecy:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
        </dependency>
```